# Spark - Dataframe writer - Extra empty file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing a strange behavior with spark.

I'm using a small dataset with only 10 rows :

```
+-----+--------------------+
|   id|       neighbourhood|
+-----+--------------------+
|47061|De Baarsjes - Oud...|
|50515|       Bos en Lommer|
|50570|       Bos en Lommer|
|20168|        Centrum-Oost|
|46386|De Pijp - Riviere...|
|50518|          Westerpark|
| 2818|Oostelijk Havenge...|
|52490|Oostelijk Havenge...|
|31080|                Zuid|
|43980|                Zuid|
+-----+--------------------+
```

After repartitionning by the column 'neighbourhood' 200 partitions are created.

I added a column in order to locate where each rows is located with the following code :

`df.select('*', spark_partition_id().alias('partition_id'))`

And the result is :

```
+-----+--------------------+------------+
|   id|       neighbourhood|partition_id|
+-----+--------------------+------------+
|47061|De Baarsjes - Oud...|          17|
|50515|       Bos en Lommer|          19|
|50570|       Bos en Lommer|          19|
|20168|        Centrum-Oost|          25|
|46386|De Pijp - Riviere...|          34|
|50518|          Westerpark|          44|
| 2818|Oostelijk Havenge...|          70|
|52490|Oostelijk Havenge...|          70|
|31080|                Zuid|         102|
|43980|                Zuid|         102|
+-----+--------------------+------------+
```

So Far So Good.

What is wrong is when I write the dataframe :

`df.write.csv('xxxxxxxxx/df_pid')`

The result is the following :

```
 - df_pid
 -------- / part-00000-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00017-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00019-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00025-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00034-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00044-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00070-.... .csv
 -------- / part-00102-.... .csv
```

As far as I can tell, the number in part-xxx corresponds to the index of the partition being written.
But what I don't understand, is why is there a part-00000-.... .csv when no data is located into partition index 0 ?

Could anyone explain ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Because of this pull request since 2.0.0 spark version https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18654.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

After re-partitioning by the column 'neighbourhood' 200 partitions were created which means 200 files but you just have 10 records so some partitions will have data and some won't. You can reduce the partition size or can use `coalesce` to reduce partitions before writing. If you reduce the partitions to 1 then only 1 file will be written under "df_pid".

Comment: I agree on the fact that some partitions will have data and some won't. That's why I added a column 'partition_id' to know on which partition the data is located.
But as you can see, there's no row where partition_id is equal to 0 and yet, there's an empty file created for the partition index 0.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a shuffle, default number of partitions created by spark are `200`. If you want to change the behavior, you must set the following property:

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
```

[Doc link.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options)

As you don't have much data, the partitions are getting created no records. When you save a partition with no data you will get an empty file.

Comment: I agree, but in this case, i only have 1 empty file, when i should get 200 files (1 per partition after the shuffle with the repartition() method) and most of them should be empty.
Maybe my question is not specific enough i will rephrase it for you.

After the repartition, we get 200 partitions. But when I save it, i get 1 file for each partition which have data stored in it + 1 extra file corresponding to index 0. Should i not have 200 files, with most of them empty ?